# Nim regex to perform once not global replace

Tags: nim-lang

How do we ask Nim regex to perform once not global replacing it with a specific string (e.g. let sided by Perl syntax) ?

```
import std/nre

var o="foo bar blah !"
    
echo o.replace( re"(\w+)", "masked")
```

it'd be:

```
$o='foo bar blah !' ;
$o =~ s/(\w+)/masked/g ;
print $o

masked masked masked !
```

not the expected

```
masked bar blah !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api for this is not currently available in standard library's modules `re` and `nre` but it is available in [nim-regex](https://github.com/nitely/nim-regex) using `limit` optional parameter (see [docs](https://nitely.github.io/nim-regex/regex.html#replace%2Cstring%2CRegex%2Cstring%2Cint)):

```
import regex

var o = "foo bar blah !"
    
echo o.replace(re"(\w+)", "masked", limit=1)
# masked bar blah !
```